# Peer discovery: What class of network algorithm prioritises low latency above all else?

Tags: distributed-systems

I'm trying to flesh out a proposed application model where all peers in a distributed network discover each other in the least possible propagation time.

But I'm reached [the limit of my knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence) of network theory and my naive search keywords return too many disparate PDF white-papers to narrow down.

So my question is: **What protocol or class of algorithm for discovering every peer in a network prioritises *low latency* over every other network characteristic?**

Comment: Do you actually need for a peer to discover every other or only the top N that have the lowest latency? The latter is far more useful in, for example, peer selection for swarm streaming.

Comment: @DanD. Unfortunately yes. No matter which way I model the specific problem I end up needing either O(N) bandwidth per node for peer discovery or O(N) bandwidth per node for indirect node traffic; and O(N) for peer discovery is more flexible in this instance providing the latency is as low as practicable. The primary problem is that this application's nodes are fundamentally heterogeneous in manner I can't sidestep since the heterogeneity is a key quality that the network is trying to replicate. :-/